# What graphic drivers i need to install so my both graphic cards could run?

Tags: drivers, ati, graphics, radeon

im new ubuntu user so i dont know much about it, i searched all over internet how and what drivers to install so my dual gpu lapotop could run both of them. I tried most of the methods still no luck. Is amd crossfire really working on ubuntu 14.04 LTS ? I tried so many times that i have no other ideas what to do, so im asking help here :D

Here is what cards i have in my laptop:
 Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] BeaverCreek [Radeon HD 6520G] 
 Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Thames [Radeon HD 7500M/7600M Series]

If needed any other info, to help me, just ask :D t.y

Comment: Crossfire requires both GPUs to be from the same GPU family according to AMD's website, but your GPUs appear to be from different families (6500M vs 7500M/7600M series). http://support.amd.com/en-us/search/faq/70 . Is it crossfire you are looking for or switchable graphics?

Answer (score 0):

Install the `xserver-xorg-video-ati` driver:

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-ati
```

Then reboot.